# Displaying Source Of Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to accomplish something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script id="ViewSource" src="someJSfile.js"/>
    <script language="javascript">
      function View() {
        var el=document.getElementById("ViewSource"); //works
        var ta=document.getElementById("ta");         //works
        ta.value=el.innerHTML;                        //doesn't work
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="ta"/>
    <a href="javascript:View();">View Javascript Source Code</a>
  </body>
</html>
// (please pardon any typos/errors, the above is just to illustrate what I mean)
```

Of course "innerHTML" doesn't work on script tags.  What property/attribute can I access to view source?

I realize this can be accomplished very easily by just clicking view source in the browser.  Am I crazy to hope it can be done with javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just fire an AJAX call and download the "someJSFile.js"? Once you downloaded it you would have access to it in a JS variable.

If you are using jQuery this can easily be done using `$.get`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Edit: In theory it shouldn't even re-download the file since it is cached in the browser (depends on your server settings and the browser settings).

- Christian

Answer (score 0):

If you set ta.innerHTML = el.innerHTML, it would at least have a chance of working.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">bleah
<script id="thescript" type="text/javascript">
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
 if (links[i].href == "http://www.google.com/") links[i].href = "http://www.blather.blorg/"
}
</script>
<br clear="all" />
<textarea id="view">
</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("view").innerHTML =
 document.getElementById("thescript").innerHTML;
</script>
```

The above seems to work, except I need to expand the size of the textarea to view all of it.

Comment: No, it wouldn't.  That's a `<textarea>`.

Comment: As SLaks mentioned, this technique only works for inline scripts, not remote scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  function View() {
    var el=document.getElementById("ViewSource"); //works
    var ta=document.getElementById("ta");         //works
    ta.value=el.text;                             //works!
  }
```